# Verifying eth0 still works after adding eth1

Tags: virtual-machines, ubuntu-14.04, ping

I am using the Virtual Machine vmware with ubuntu.
I've added a network adapter - eth1 and have assigned an ip address and mac address. but now that I try to connect to the internet, it doesn't work. for instance I have tried 
ping , but it prints out this message.

root@ubuntu:~# ping -c 1 www.bbc.co.uk

ping: www.bbc.co.uk: Temporary failure in name resolution

Any advice what the fix might be for this issue, please?

Comment: The order in which Ubuntu discovers the adapters may not be the same as VMware.  Make sure that eth1 isn't the old eth0.

Comment: How did the adapters get the names `eth0` and `eth1`? They should have other consistent names, such as `ens160` or `ens192`. Do you have open-vm-tools installed?

Comment: not sure about the names. It has self assigned automatically. When I call ifconfig -a, then both eth0 and eth1 are apreaing.

Answer (score 0):

This indicates that there is a problem with DNS name resolution.

Look at `/etc/resolv.conf`. Probably your second interface announces a DNS server that overwrites the entry from the DNS server on the first interface, but the second DNS server is not reachable.

If you run your own resolver in the VM, the second interface may set a default route that doesn't work.

Comment: well, when I go to the network connections, there is Wired Connection 2 (for etho ) and Wired Connection 1 (for eth1 ).  The setup is correct.

Comment: in the file /etc/resolv.conf, there is only one line nameserver 127.0.0.53
the rest is comments.

Comment: I called this command systemd-resolve --status

at the end it says current scope: none

Comment: If the setup is correct, then everything is fine. Does your resolver at `127.0.0.53` work or not? Is it the correct address for your resolver?

Comment: Not sure how I can check if it is the correct address for the resolver.

Comment: running ifconfig -a will show me  inet 192.168.1.39 for eth0. I have manullay set the eth1 ip address to  inet 10.0.0.1. When I tried to pint eth0 to an address, it won't work.